# Empty QMainWindow, PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qmainwindow

I have two QMainWindows, I'm trying to call one from the other one. The window opens but , it is empty and does not respond until the parent window is closed.

My Code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,None)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(184, 165)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 184, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton , QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.gone)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

    def gone(self):
        mainwindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        self.mw2 = Ui_MainWindow1()
        self.mw2.setupUi(mainwindow)
        self.mw2.show()

class Ui_MainWindow1(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,None)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(170, 175)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 101, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 170, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "This is second", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

def startmain():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow() # <-- Instantiate QMainWindow object.
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    startmain()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you are creating `QMainWindow` objects when your `Ui_MainWindow` and `Ui_MainWindow1` classes are subclasses of `QMainWindow`.  Basically, you have four main windows, when you only need two.

Instead of creating `QMainWindow`s called `MainWindow`, and setting things up in them, set up each window in itself by using `self` instead of `MainWindow`.  The following appears to work for me, in that the first window has a button, and clicking it opens the second with a label in it:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,None)

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("self"))
        self.resize(184, 165)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 184, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        self.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(self)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi()
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton , QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.gone)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def retranslateUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

    def gone(self):
        self.mw2 = Ui_MainWindow1()
        self.mw2.setupUi()
        self.mw2.show()

class Ui_MainWindow1(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,None)

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("self"))
        self.resize(170, 175)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 101, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 170, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        self.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(self)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def retranslateUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "This is second", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

def startmain():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi()
    ui.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    startmain()
```

Comment: Thanx Luke, I just wanted to the child window goes in behind the parent and is unactive until the parent is closed